# SQL query - Finding if something exists only if a field is a certain number (MS SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need some help here.

How can i say, if a = 10 then check if c = any b's in mytable

```
select *
from mytable
where a IN(5,10,15,20)
```

(start of example query.)

For those that cant understand the above.
I WANT to retrieve all rows where a is 5,10,15,20. and I WANT to only check if b = c if A = 10

Comment: How is `where a IN(5,10,15,20)` related to your question at all?

Comment: becuase i am looking to retrieve records where a is any of these, but only want an exists criteria if the row it is retrieving is 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.a IN (5,10,15,20)
AND (t.a <> 10 OR EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM mytable t2
    WHERE  t.c = t2.b
) )
```

Comment: I want my query to return more than just if a = 10 using this I wouldnt retrieve any records with 5,15 or 20

Comment: @Tim_Schmelter with this query will it only show "a = 5" if c and b are equal? I only want this "extra" criteria if a = 10. :/

Comment: @Mike: your question is not clear at all. You should edit it to provide sample data and a desired result.

Comment: I give the sql i have, and what I want from it which clearly says if a = 10 then check if b = c .. its really not that difficult to read. I dont know if you think everyone asking a question is dull or something but the sql you give is pretty simple

Comment: @Mike: no i think that i've understood your requirement. Have a lok at my last edit. You need to check `t.a <> 10 OR ...`